# Set maximum height of column headers - NatTable

Tags: java, swt, nattable

I have column headers that use a `VerticalTextPainter`.

If I set `setCalculateByTextHeight` and `setCalculateByTextLength` to true is resizes the columns to fit all of the text inside the cells correctly.

Sometimes the headers will have a lot of text in them so I would like them to have a maximum height.

If I stop using`setCalculateByTextHeight` and `setCalculateByTextLength` then the cells aren't resized at all so they just show `...`.

How could I go about doing this?

**Update**

```
@Override
protected void setNewMinLength(ILayerCell cell, int contentHeight) {

    final ILayer layer = cell.getLayer();
    final int cellLength = cell.getBounds().height;

    if (contentHeight < MAXIMUM_HEIGHT && cellLength < contentHeight) {
        layer.doCommand(new RowResizeCommand(layer, cell.getRowPosition(), contentHeight));
    } else {
        layer.doCommand(new RowResizeCommand(layer, cell.getRowPosition(), MAXIMUM_HEIGHT));
    }
}
```

**Override paintControl in NatTable**

```
@Override
public void paintControl(final PaintEvent event) {
    super.paintControl(event);

    /**
     * After first time rendering we stop column/row headers calculating their
     * height/lengths. This allows the user to resize the column/row headers after
     * the NatTable has been rendered.
     */
    if (firstRender) {
        columnHeaderPainter.setCalculateByTextHeight(false);
        columnHeaderPainter.setCalculateByTextLength(false);

        rowHeaderPainter.setCalculateByTextHeight(false);
        rowHeaderPainter.setCalculateByTextLength(false);
        firstRender = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in mechanism to specify a max height or width. Either you configure that the height should be calculated based on the content or set a fixed height.

I think you could achieve this by subclassing the `VerticalTextPainter` and overriding setNewMinLength() to only execute a `RowResizeCommand` if the contentHeight is bigger than the cellLength and the cellLength is not bigger than your maximum. And of course the `RowResizeCommand` should only resize to your specified maximum then.

Performing the check on any other place would probably result in an endless processing of cell height resizing.

Comment: I've updated the question. I've tried checking the maximum in `setNewMinLength`. This is now limiting the height but now if I want to resize the columns by dragging it will always snap back to the original place. This makes sense as without overriding it would normally only resize if it was below the content size. 
Is it possible to write a command that could do what I want? Then it could set the size correctly when the table is first created and the user can then resize it to however they please?

Comment: Then you need a differ approach. The painter will always resize on rendering. You probably need to implement an auto resize mechanism like the AutoResizePaintListener that unregisters itself after the first rendering.

Comment: That sounds a lot more like what I'm looking for. Where would I find this? I can't find `AutoResizePaintListener` in 1.5.0.

Comment: It was introduced after 1.5 so you need the latest SNAPSHOT build.

Comment: Are there any alternative methods of achieving this in 1.5? We can't use an unstable build in production.

Comment: You can check the implementation and try to implement the same yourself with 1.5

Comment: The approach I've taken is overriding `paintControl` in `NatTable` (As shown above).  I can then change the painters to stop calculating size after they have first been rendered. This seems like a straight forward approach although not necessarily the best.